# Как сделать, чтобы событие перетаскивания срабатывало на указанном элементе

Tags: javascript, html

Вот код:

```js
function $(el) {
  return document.querySelector(el);
}

function ODS(e) {
  e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", event.target.id)
  e.currentTarget.style.opacity = "0.2";
}

function ODO(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

function OD(e) {
  const id = e.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  const drag = $("#" + id);
  const dropzone = $("#elem_container" + e.target.id[e.target.id.length - 1]);

  drag.style.opacity = "1";

  dropzone.appendChild(drag);
  e.dataTransfer.clearData();
}
width = window.innerWidth;
$("#box1").style.left = width / 45 - $("#box1").style.width + "px"
$("#box2").style.left = width / 2.75 - $("#box2").style.width + "px"
$("#box3").style.left = width / 1.42 - $("#box3").style.width + "px"
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #4b4;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.box {
  width: 350px;
  margin: 5em auto;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  box-shadow: 2px 3px 7px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: -60px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.bold_text {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.element {
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 9px #ccc;
  padding-top: 0.1px;
  padding-bottom: 0.1px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.element:hover {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

.element_text {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.create {
  font-weight: 200;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.create:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="box1" class="box" ondragover="ODO(event)" ondrop="OD(event)">
      <p class="bold_text"> &nbsp; &nbsp; 1</p>
      <div id="elem_container1">
        <div class="element" id="element1" draggable="true" ondragstart="ODS(event)" onclick="this.remove()">
          <p class="element_text">1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="element" id="element2" draggable="true" ondragstart="ODS(event)" onclick="this.remove()">
          <p class="element_text">2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="box2" class="box" ondragover="ODO(event)" ondrop="OD(event)">
      <p class="bold_text"> &nbsp; &nbsp; 2</p>
      <div id="elem_container2"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="box3" class="box" ondragover="ODO(event)" ondrop="OD(event)">
      <p class="bold_text"> &nbsp; &nbsp; 3</p>
      <div id="elem_container3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при перетаскивании элемента не надо было пытаться попасть в `elem_container`, а можно было просто перетащить элемент в `boxN`

Я пытался задать `id` каждому элементу внутри, но это очень долго

Можно как-то сделать, чтобы если ты отпускал элемент на `div` `boxN`, то чтобы оно не смотрело на каком элементе в `div` ты отпустил *ЛКМ*, а чтобы всё было так, будто ты отпустил элемент на `div`

То есть например:

```html
<div id="box1">
    <p class="text">1</p>
    <div id="elem_container1">
</div>
```

Если ты отпустишь элемент на `<p class="text>`, то чтобы всё было так, будто ты отпустил перетаскиваемый элемент на `<div id="box1">`, или на `<div id="elem_container1>`

Вот весь код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TODO List</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: #4b4;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            
        }
        .box {
            width: 350px;
            margin: 5em auto;
            padding-left: 10px;
            padding-right: 10px;
            background-color: #eee;
            border-radius: 0.5em;
            box-shadow: 2px 3px 7px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
            float: left;
            position: absolute;
            top: -60px;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }
        .bold_text {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .element {
            background-color: #fff;
            cursor: pointer;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 9px #ccc;
            padding-top: 0.1px;
            padding-bottom: 0.1px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            margin-top: 6px;
        }
        .element:hover {
            background-color: #f6f6f6;
        }
        .element_text {
            padding-left: 10px;
        }
        .create {
            font-weight: 200;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .create:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding-top: 2px;
            padding-bottom: 2px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="box1" class="box" ondragover="ODO(event)" ondrop="OD(event)">
            <p id="bold_text1" class="bold_text"> &nbsp; &nbsp; Нужно сделать</p>
            <div id="elem_container1">
                <div class="element" id="element1" draggable="true" ondragstart="ODS(event)" onclick="this.remove()">
                    <p class="element_text">Тест</p>
                </div>
                <div class="element" id="element2" draggable="true" ondragstart="ODS(event)" onclick="this.remove()">
                    <p class="element_text">Тест2</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p id="create1" class="create"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;+ Добавить</p>
        </div>

        <div id="box2" class="box" ondragover="ODO(event)" ondrop="OD(event)">
            <p id="bold_text2" class="bold_text"> &nbsp; &nbsp; В процессе</p>
            <div id="elem_container2"></div>
            <p id="create2" class="create"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;+ Добавить</p>
        </div>

        <div id="box3" class="box" ondragover="ODO(event)" ondrop="OD(event)">
            <p id="bold_text3" class="bold_text"> &nbsp; &nbsp; Готово</p>
            <div id="elem_container3"></div>
            <p id="create3" class="create"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;+ Добавить</p>
        </div>

        <script>
            function $(el) {
                return document.querySelector(el);
            }
            function ODS(e) {
                e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", event.target.id)
                e.currentTarget.style.opacity = "0.2";
            }
            function ODO(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            function OD(e) {
                const id = e.dataTransfer.getData("text");
                const drag = $("#" + id);
                const dropzone = $("#elem_container" + e.target.id[e.target.id.length - 1]);

                drag.style.opacity = "1";

                dropzone.appendChild(drag);
                e.dataTransfer.clearData();
            }
            width = window.innerWidth;
            $("#box1").style.left = width / 45 - $("#box1").style.width + "px"
            $("#box2").style.left = width / 2.75 - $("#box2").style.width + "px"
            $("#box3").style.left = width / 1.42 - $("#box3").style.width + "px"
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: добавь минимально реализованный код с проблемой гляну как можно реальизовать то что ты хочеш

Comment: так оно и так работает правильно в чем проблема? добавь height к boxN и сам убедишся